# Why can I create tags at 150 rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was wondering why is that I can create tags at 150 rep only. On other sites that limit is 500 rep and how come I can retag questions 200 rep

**EDIT:<s>For that I have to edit the question too which means I have to have 2000 rep for that.</s>**

Also for the nominate moderators on other sites you only need 150 rep to vote for mods.

Sorry but I didn't read that part normally. it changes site-by-site but tags don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see

[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)